# Find the probability that X < Y

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure the probability that $X < Y$ with:

$$X, Y \in \mathbb R^+;\ X\in [0,5] ; \ Y \in [0,2]$$
What is the law to use?

Comment: What is the distribution of X? of Y? You are just stating their supports (range of values).

Comment: What's the *joint distribution* of $X$ and $Y$? Without that, you cannot answer this. You could e.g. have $X$ uniformly distribution on $[0,5]$ and $Y = X\frac{2}{5}$, then $Y \in [0,2]$ and $Y < X$ *always*, i.e. $X < Y$ never.

Comment: Let assume _X and Y are random values_ between those plots and totally _independent_. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** the random variables are independent and **IF** they are uniformly distributed on the range you indicate then $E(Y)=1$ and $P(X\lt y)=\frac15y$ for every $y$ in $(0,2)$ hence $P(X\lt Y)=\frac15E(Y)=\frac15$.

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniform on the intervals $(0,u)$ and $(0,v)$ respectively, with $u\geqslant v$, then $P(X\lt Y)=\frac{v}{2u}$. Finally, in the same situation but with $u\leqslant v$, $P(X\lt Y)=1-\frac{u}{2v}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming independence:
$$\Pr(X<Y)= \int_{0}^5 Pr(x<Y) \cdot f_X(x)dx= \int_{0}^5 (1-F_Y(x)) \cdot f_X(x)dx$$